# vue-test-utils + typescript type for wrapper.vm

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-test-utils, typescript-eslint, vitest

sitting on a issue here. ever used typescript + vue-test-utils and tried to manipulate a value for the test like:
`wrapper.vm.aCoolRefValueToManipulate = 'something much cooler'`?
well i tried. and it worked but ts linter goes crazy on this one because it don't know what `aCoolRefValueToManipulate` inside `vm` is.

anyone a idea how to fix this?

[image: linter error]

linter tells me:

```
Property 'showTopDown' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{}>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>; ... 10 more ...; $watch(source: string | Function, cb: Function, options?: WatchOptions<...> | undefined): WatchStopHandle; } & Readonly<...> & Sha...'.ts(2339)
```

---

## Solution

some cool dude helped me on the official [Vue Discord Server](https://discord.com/invite/HBherRA).

```js
(wrapper.vm as any).aCoolRefValueToManipulate
```

Answer (score 4):

Do we have any other ways without using "any" to access into methods of wrapper.vm?

I just found this thing that can try:

```
type TestWrapper<T> = VueWrapper<ComponentPublicInstance & T>
let wrapper: TestWrapper<Partial<{ myMethod: () => void }>>

wrapper.vm.myMethod?.()
```